# How to create blank file in google drive using drive api with our own extension

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I want to create a blank file with .h extension and store in google drive. Please let me know how can I create a blank file using api of google drive.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but I would try creating the file with the following params:

1. title -> (filename).h
2. mime-type -> 'text/plain'